# Checking two attributes in an object

Tags: c#, equals, actionresult

I am coding a C# MVC5 Internet Application and have a question about checking an objects attributes.

I retrieve an Asset object from a DbSet, and I want to check to ensure that the Asset has either a userName of the current user, or a category of DefaultMapMarker. If neither of these are true, I wish to show a HttpNotFound page.

Is the below code correct?

```
if (!asset.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker" || asset.userName != User.Identity.GetUserName()))
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I meant to ask if the above code achieves the same as this following code:

```
if (!asset.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker"))
{
    if (asset.userName != User.Identity.GetUserName())
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks okay, what error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. The first will pass if only one condition is correct. But the second will check both conditions to excecute the action.
the second is equal to:

```
if (!asset.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker") && asset.userName != User.Identity.GetUserName()))
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not achieve the same thing.

Your first statement with the logical or says "If this condition is met OR the other is met: {...}"

Your second statement says "If condition is met AND this condition is met {...}", which could be translated into:

```
if (!asset.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker" && asset.userName != User.Identity.GetUserName()))
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

So the answer to your question is: No, they don't achieve the same thing. If you want a `HttpNotFoundException` to be raised if both conditions are met you have to chain your conditions with a logical AND (&&)

//edit: before the nitpicking starts. Yes I am aware, that the order is relevant in his second code snippet, but I choose to ignore it for the sake of the problem.